# Making api call with start index and max results

Tags: android, api, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch videos from channel with start index 11 and max results 40..But is is always showing top videos starting from index 0..

I tried

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=xyz&channelId=UCzUYuC_9XdUUdrnyLii8WYg&part=snippet,id&orderby=date&start-index=11&maxResults=40
```

I tried this also

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=xyz&channelId=UCzUYuC_9XdUUdrnyLii8WYg&part=snippet,id&orderby=date&start-index=11&max-results=40
```

but they fetch videos starting from index 0.Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use pageToken in place of start-index, pageToken is like pagination.

Comment: what value should i put in pageToken?